# xargs parallel tar pipeline

Tags: parallel-processing, pipe, tar, pipeline, xargs

I'm trying to copy a very large filesystem using a parallel pipeline of tar create/extract jobs using `xargs`. I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.

```
find image -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -print|xargs -P 48 tar cf - --files-from|(cd /testfiles; tar xf -)
```

I get these errors:

> xargs: tar: terminated by signal 13
>   xargs: tar: terminated by signal 13

But if I execute the same command without the `-P` option, it runs. It's just single threaded and will take forever to do 50 million files across the 700K subdirectories.

The following works, but ist slow:

```
find image -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -print|xargs tar cf - --files-from|(cd /testfiles; tar xf -)
```

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your parallel pipeline *stdout* is getting consumed by a "single" *stdin* from `|(cd /testfiles; tar xf -)`

So, you need to "also" parallelize the `tar xf -` part, a possible solution can be treating that pipeline as a "mini-script", then getting xargs passed arguments with `$@`:

```
find image -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -print| \
  xargs -P 48 sh -c 'tar cf - --files-from $@ | tar -C /testfiles -xf -' --
```

Btw also I'd be careful with the `-P 48`, start with more *frugal* values until you find a comfy tradeoff for the I/O impact of above.

Answer (score -1):

Using `-n 1` in `xargs` will make tar run with each output line from the `find` command just before.

```sh
find image -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -print|xargs -n 1 -P 48 tar cf - --files-from|(cd /testfiles; tar xf -)
```